# Search File by Capitalized First Letters in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, file-search

In many IDEs (e.g. IntelliJ, Eclipse) when I want to search for a file, I can type just the capitals of the CamelCase-style named file (e.g. AC-> ApprovalContainer).

However, VSCode does not seem to match the Capital Letters. AC could result in any File, having the letters (ignoring case) in that order, like Action, Accordion, even App.css, having the 'c' only in the file type:

[image]

Is there a setting or extension for that?